# Joining 2 tables in SELECT(MYSQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have these two tables. The connecting "key"  is conID which is included in both tables.
So now i would like to write select statement which would give me something like this:

John Smith dairy22 Texas 4000 smth4

Mike Situation glenn32 Jersey 1000 smth1
...

**> table "people":**

```
NUM   Name lastName  address    conID
-----------------------------------------
  1    John  Smith     dairy22   Texas
  2    Mike  Situation glenn32   Jersey
  3    Duke  Nukem     haris48   NYork
  4    Queen Lisa      court84   London
```

**> table "countries"**

```
conID   postNum   region
-------------------------
Jersey  1000      smth1
NYork   2000      smth2
London  3000      smth3
Texas   4000      smth4
```

**! -> NUM is AUTO INCREMENT primary key, which i dont want it the output if possible.**

Thanks for help in advance :))

Comment: a simple INNER JOIN will gives you what you want -> SELECT p.name, p.lastname, p.address, c.postNum, c.region FROM people p INNER JOIN coutries c ON c.conID = p.conID

Comment: you should accept one of the answers.. or provide more feedback if there isn't one that helps you. as an example: the difference between two types of joins might be what you want to happen if in one of the tables the record does not exist..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should return the rows you want, based on the `num` column:

```
SELECT Name, lastName, address, people.conID, postNum, region 
FROM people 
JOIN countries 
ON people.conID = countries.conID 
WHERE num=1
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the following MySQL query:**

```
SELECT
    Name,
    lastName,
    address,
    people.conID,
    postNum,
    region
FROM
    people
JOIN
    countries
        ON people.conID = countries.conID
WHERE
    num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
SELECT name, lastName, address, people.conID, postNum, region
FROM people
 JOIN countries ON people.conID = countries.conID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You SQL query should look like this:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.lastName, p.address, p.conID, c.postNum, c.region
FROM people p 
LEFT JOIN countries c ON p.conID = c.conID
```

Answer (score 0):

Good ole [`USING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) clause:

```
SELECT Name, lastName, address, p.conID, postNum, region FROM people p
INNER JOIN countries USING (conID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, lastName, address, people.conID, postnum, region
FROM people JOIN countries ON people.conID = countries.conID;
```